How to change Google Material Symbol fill on demand using Angular directive?
I currently have my own npm font icon library that I created and I have been asked to implement the modality where, using my directive below, if someone writes <div icon="search fill"> , aknowledging the 'fill' keyword, the icon's style changes from outlined to filled with the current color, as per the example below.

I fetch Google's Symbols icons using a stylesheet in my index.html, specifically
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,1,0" />    

The last elements represent the weight and fill of the font, so predefined.
This is my icon directive, which includes other functionalities.
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[icon]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class IconDirective {
  private _iconName: string = '';
  private _spin: boolean = false;
  private _size: string | undefined;
  private _flipHorizontal: boolean = false;
  private _flipVertical: boolean = false;
  private _color: string | undefined;
  private _fill: boolean = false;
  private _rotate: number = 0;

  @Input('icon')
  set icon(value: string) {
    const parts = value.split(' ');
    this._iconName = parts[0];

    console.log(this._iconName, value)

    this._spin = parts.includes('spin');

    this._flipHorizontal = parts.includes('flip-horizontal');

    this._flipVertical = parts.includes('flip-vertical');

    this._size = parts.find(part => part.match(/^[0-5]x$/)) || undefined; // Default to 1x

    const colorPart = parts.find(part => part.startsWith('color-'));
    this._color = colorPart ? colorPart.split('-')[1] : undefined;

    this._rotate = parseInt(parts.find(part => part.startsWith('rotate-'))?.split('-')[1] || '0');

    this.updateIcon();
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setupLazyLoading();
  }

  private setupLazyLoading(): void {
    const options = {
      root: null, // observes changes in the viewport
      threshold: 0.01, // trigger when 1% of the element is visible
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          this.updateIcon();
          observer.unobserve(entry.target); // Stop observing once loaded
        }
      });
    }, options);

    observer.observe(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

  private updateIcon(): void {
    // Clear previous classes
    this.el.nativeElement.className = '';

    if (!this._iconName) {
      return;
    }

    console.log('Setting icon');
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'textContent', this._iconName);
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'material-symbols-outlined');

    // Apply size, spin, and flip classes
    if (this._spin) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'spin');
    }
    if (this._flipHorizontal) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'flip-horizontal');
    }
    if (this._flipVertical) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'flip-vertical');
    }
    if (this._size) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, `icon-${this._size}`);
    }
    if (this._color) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'color', this._color);
    }
    if (this._rotate) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'transform', `rotate(${this._rotate}deg)`); // Rotate icon
    }
  }
}

How do I implement the fill? I have previously tried doing something similar to the spin and flip functionalities, and the modifying the css and setting .[icon] { fill: currentColor } but it did not work.
How do I go about this?
